# Not able to get the count of a specific ID from a json using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to get the count of an ID existence by comparing it with another json. however in a way i am successful but for few numbers it is getting incorrect count.

```
var outputProducts = [
    { outputId:'1', inputId:   '3', opName: "outMacy"    },
    { outputId:'2', inputId:   '3', opName: "outMacy2"   },
    { outputId:'3', inputId:   '3', opName: "outMacy3"   },
    { outputId:'4', inputId: '235', opName: "EXPENCE"    },
    { outputId:'5', inputId: '235', opName: "opEXPENCE"  },
    { outputId:'6', inputId: '235', opName: "opEXPENCE1" },
    { outputId:'8', inputId: '235', opName: "opEXPENCE3" },
    { outputId:'7', inputId: '215', opName: "JCPenny"    }
];
```

this is how my json looks like from which i have to get

```
temp = [
    { name:   "3", shownName: 3 },
    { name: "215", shownName: 1 },
    { name: "235", shownName: 4 }
]
```

instead it is giving me

```
temp = [
    { name:   "3", shownName: 7 },
    { name: "215", shownName: 1 },
    { name: "235", shownName: 4 }
]
```

i feel it is looking 3 in the whole json that way it is getting the count of 235 in which it has 3 and showing it as 7 instead of 3

here is my plunker(whole json is not seen because of PUSH error however you can see the generated temp json with the incorrect count of name:"3", shownName:7)

https://plnkr.co/edit/aIdlWUS7UFb91hKC4nqx?p=preview

Here is my code

```
var outputProducts = [
    { outputId:'1', inputId:   '3', opName: "outMacy"    },
    { outputId:'2', inputId:   '3', opName: "outMacy2"   },
    { outputId:'3', inputId:   '3', opName: "outMacy3"   },
    { outputId:'4', inputId: '235', opName: "EXPENCE"    },
    { outputId:'5', inputId: '235', opName: "opEXPENCE"  },
    { outputId:'6', inputId: '235', opName: "opEXPENCE1" },
    { outputId:'8', inputId: '235', opName: "opEXPENCE3" },
    { outputId:'7', inputId: '215', opName: "JCPenny"    }
];

$scope.outputProducts = outputProducts;

var keysCount, copyOfOutputData, keysCount2, uniqueInputFiles=[], outputFilesCount=[];
keysCount = Object.keys(outputProducts).length;

console.log("$scopes.", $scope.outputProducts);

for (i = 0; i < keysCount; i += 1) {
    if (uniqueInputFiles.indexOf(outputProducts[i].inputId) === -1) {
       uniqueInputFiles.push(outputProducts[i].inputId);
    }
}

console.log("uniqueInputFiles", uniqueInputFiles);

copyOfOutputData = angular.copy(uniqueInputFiles);
keysCount2 = Object.keys(copyOfOutputData).length;

for (i = 0; i < keysCount2; i += 1) {

    outputFilesCount = $filter('filter')( outputProducts, { inputId: copyOfOutputData[i] } ).length;
    temp = {
        name     : copyOfOutputData[i],
        shownName: outputFilesCount
    };
    console.log("temp", temp)

    $scope.inputFilesWithCount.push(temp);
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filter` filter is not an exact comparison, it is a pattern when matched using an object. So when you pass it...

```
{
    inputId: '3'
}
```

... you are actually asking to find any value that has `3` within the property `inputId`. For your example, something like this would be more friendly:

```
$scope.outputProducts = [
    { outputId:'1', inputId:   '3', opName: "outMacy"    },
    { outputId:'2', inputId:   '3', opName: "outMacy2"   },
    { outputId:'3', inputId:   '3', opName: "outMacy3"   },
    { outputId:'4', inputId: '235', opName: "EXPENCE"    },
    { outputId:'5', inputId: '235', opName: "opEXPENCE"  },
    { outputId:'6', inputId: '235', opName: "opEXPENCE1" },
    { outputId:'8', inputId: '235', opName: "opEXPENCE3" },
    { outputId:'7', inputId: '215', opName: "JCPenny"    }
];

var counts = {};

angular.forEach($scope.outputProducts, function (product) {
    if (typeof counts[product.inputId] === 'undefined') {
        counts[product.inputId] = 0;
    }

    counts[product.inputId] = counts[product.inputId] + 1;
});

$scope.inputFilesWithCount = [];
angular.forEach(counts, function (total, inputId) {
    $scope.inputFilesWithCount.push({
        name: inputId,
        shownName: total
    });
});
```

This will generate the values that you are hoping for (in a cleaner, more efficient way) as all you are really doing is updating a count.

Answer (score 1):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var outputProducts = [
    { outputId:'1', inputId:   '3', opName: "outMacy"    },
    { outputId:'2', inputId:   '3', opName: "outMacy2"   },
    { outputId:'3', inputId:   '3', opName: "outMacy3"   },
    { outputId:'4', inputId: '235', opName: "EXPENCE"    },
    { outputId:'5', inputId: '235', opName: "opEXPENCE"  },
    { outputId:'6', inputId: '235', opName: "opEXPENCE1" },
    { outputId:'8', inputId: '235', opName: "opEXPENCE3" },
    { outputId:'7', inputId: '215', opName: "JCPenny"    }
];
function inc(t,x) {
  var i = x.inputId;
  t[i]? t[i].count++:(t[i] = {count: 1})
 return t;
 }
var x = outputProducts.reduce((t,x)=> inc(t,x),{});
var y = Object.keys(x).map(v=>({name: v, shownName: x[v].count}))
console.log(y)
```